# How can I make these javascript functions universally applicable to any desired element?

Tags: javascript, function, universal, reduce

In the following code I want to reduce these 5 functions down to 3.

The first function `toggle_visibility()` is already made universal by passing the id when I call the function from my html, however, I have to repeat the next two functions `thankYouText_Change()` and `resettxt()` because I don't know how to store the value of the `Item` variable, nor the `p` or `OK_button` variables and pass them to the next function so that they can be used by the other functions.

My goal is to figure out how to reduce these to a set of 3 functions that can be accessed at anytime in my html and applied to any and all relevant elements simply by using `onClick="function_foo('desired_element_foo')`, without having to have a separate set of functions for each time I want to use them on a different element.

I think that in order to do this I also need to know how to make the variables `p` and `OK_Button` have values that will automatically change and be stored based upon the id that I send to them/access them with.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var Item = document.getElementById(id);

    if (Item.style.display == 'block') {
        Item.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        Item.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
function thankYouText_Change() {
    var p = document.getElementById("thanksForEmail");
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById("okButton");

    if (p.innerHTML == 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.') {
        OK_Button.style.display = 'none';
        p.innerHTML = "Returning to page...";
        setTimeout("toggle_visibility('msgSend'), resettxt()", 500);
    }
}
function resettxt() {
    var p = document.getElementById("thanksForEmail");
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById("okButton");

    if (p.innerHTML == 'Returning to page...') {
        p.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.';
        OK_Button.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
//Start of repeated functions for second div and button elements
function thankYouText_Change2() {
    var p = document.getElementById("thanksForEmail2");
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById("okButton2");

    if (p.innerHTML == 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.') {
        OK_Button.style.display = 'none';
        p.innerHTML = "Returning to page...";
        setTimeout("toggle_visibility('msgSend2'), resettxt2()", 500);
    }
}
function resettxt2() {
    var p = document.getElementById("thanksForEmail2");
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById("okButton2");

    if (p.innerHTML == 'Returning to page...') {
        p.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.';
        OK_Button.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a first pass, you could simplify this to something like this:

```
function thankYouText_Change(pId, okId, msgSendId){
    var p = document.getElementById(pId);
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById(okId);

    if(p.innerHTML == 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.'){
        OK_Button.style.display = 'none';
        p.innerHTML = "Returning to page...";
        setTimeout(function(){
          toggle_visibility(msgSendId);
            resettxt(pId, okId);
        }, 500);
    }
}

function resettxt(pId, okId){
    var p = document.getElementById(pId);
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById(okId);

    if(p.innerHTML == 'Returning to page...'){
    p.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.';
    OK_Button.style.display = 'block';}
}
```

And then for each set of elements on the page, you just need to call `thankYouText_Change` with the correct IDs for each of the 3 related elements.

For a 2nd pass, you could simplify both of my above functions into one, so that you don't need to re-call `document.getElementById` on the same elements more than once (not significant, but I also like to declare everything with `var` - variables and functions alike):

```
var thankYouText_Change = function(pId, okId, msgSendId){
    var p = document.getElementById(pId);
    var OK_Button = document.getElementById(okId);

    if(p.innerHTML == 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.'){
        OK_Button.style.display = 'none';
        p.innerHTML = "Returning to page...";
        setTimeout(function(){
          toggle_visibility(msgSendId);
            if(p.innerHTML == 'Returning to page...'){
                p.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.';
                OK_Button.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

(Note that this eliminates the need for a `resettxt` function.)

Comment: Thank you so much. could I ask one more favor of you... I'm pretty sure I understand whats going on here, but could you explain to me why this works just so I can get an explanation to store in my brain so that I could be able to explain it to someone else?  Also, in specific could you explain why i have to use setTimeout(function(){call_other_functions_here}) rather than separating them with commas?

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob - In specific, your calls within `setTimeout` should have been separated by semicolons - not commas.  Using the function call just makes this so much easier to work with - especially with passing of parameters, otherwise you need to start worrying about escaping your argument values, etc.  The rest of this is just organizing the code and arguments so that you don't need the multiple functions.

Comment: Yeah, the second pass makes sense, it's basically just cutting and pasting the resettxt function into the setTimeout section rather than having it as a separate function. (I think)

Comment: So just to be clear on the first pass... by using the function() within the setTimeout() I am making it easy/simple to pass the pId and okId parameters to whichever function I decide pass them too?  ...and then when I write that function (which in this case was resettxt() ) as long as I define those as parameters within that function it will work because the parameters and their respective values are being passed along?